# How to add restrictions to a PDF file so it will be locked and unavailable for editing or copying content, preferably using Ghostscript or Java?

Tags: java, android, ghostscript

i was looking everywhere to solve this issue,all solutions are about unlocking PDF but nothing about adding restrictions or locking PDF files for editing such as copying text or photos so I'm looking for a way to achieve that using Java or Ghostscript .

Answer (score 1):

Set `-sOwnerPassword=` when using Ghostscript, in this case the Ghostscript documentation is in
*/ghostpdl/gs/doc/ps2pdf.htm*

Answer (score -1):

I'd advise you to start with section 12 of the specification, 12.8.4 Permissions has information about this matter.

Specification can be found here [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)